# Why does my output have elements before the NULL, and how can I refactor a for loop with "list" in R to use something more elegant

Tags: r, for-loop

I have heard that for loops are bad R style.  I have a for loop that uses "list" to assemble the output, and even if the control flow of "for" is tolerable, the output is not very readable.

Here is my original code:

```
longlist<-c("apple","orange","red snapper")
sublist<-c("ap","er")

altgrepper1<-function(substringList, longstringList){
  #go through the list of short strings 
  #check to see whether any of the short strings is a substring
  #of any of the long strings
  output2<-NULL
  for (i in 1:length(substringList)){  
      output1<-grep(substringList[i],longstringList)  
    output2<-list(output2,output1)
  }
  output2
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 3


[[2]]
[1] 3
```

I am very surprised that the output has anything preceding the NULL, so clearly I don't understand how list works.  This output makes sense to me on a toy example, but I'm sure I would rapidly get confused if I tried to understand output from a real data set.

So perhaps the highest priority is to return a better-structured sort of output - perhaps a list, perhaps an array.  But to do that, it might be better to eliminate the for loop and use lapply or some other R syntax.

I'm sorry for the newbie question, but I really don't see why my output looks this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, the problem is in `output2<-list(output2,output1)` within the loop.  Your output actually has a list of a list.

`for` loops are not necessarily "bad R style".  I think it depends on personal preference and R coding standards (or some people).

That being said, there is a strong case to be made about the `apply` functions, namely `apply`, `sapply`, and `lapply`.  If I were you, I would read `?apply`, run all the examples, and then every time you write a `for` loop, ask yourself if it can be done with one of these `apply` functions.

Here's a nice way to look at a comparison of your objects `sublist` and `longlist`

```
> sapply(sublist, function(x) grep(x, longlist, value = TRUE))
$ap
[1] "apple"       "red snapper"

$er
[1] "red snapper"
```

`lapply` always returns output as a list, `sapply` does not. But in this case, `sapply` makes the result easier to understand.  Compare to

```
> lapply(sublist, function(x) grep(x, longlist, value = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "apple"       "red snapper"

[[2]]
[1] "red snapper"
```

Notice that `lapply` does not automatically attach `names` to the result, making the result from `sapply` easier to comprehend here.

Once I learned about the `apply` family of functions, two things happened.  One, I never used another `for` loop in R.  And two, R programming became really exciting for me. To each their own though.

Comment: good for introducing the wonders of sapply, I was going to add this. but you just beat me to it

Comment: These two versions of the functionality are very elegant! That's the kind of R code I've been trying to write, and now that you've given me these examples, I'm going to practice writing variations to try to get the hang of it.  Thank you - I hope R programming similarly becomes exciting for me with the apply family.

Comment: Thanks. :) They are most useful inside the body of functions, in my opinion.  And there isn't a need to allocate a vector beforehand, which is also nice.

Answer (score 1):

The first item of output 2 is 'NULL'. This what you are assigning before the for loop.
Within the for loop, you are appending the output of grep (stored in output1) to output2 with your line `output2<-list(output2,output1)`. NULL is special type of object in R. Read ?is.null for more details. When you assign it to another object, it is similar though not the same
as assigning a missing value

try this

```
output2 <-NULL
output2 <-list(output2,2)
output2
```

you will get an idea of why your output looks like the way it does.

also please have a look at `%in%`.

Comment: To give you an idea of my newbieness, I had to try several times before I figured out that I needed backticks in help(`%in%`).  But once I read that %in% is a shortcut to match, I was able to look at match.  I'll have to write some examples using match and see if I can understand it a bit more.  As for your hint on the use of [index1][index2] in list output, thanks.  I had to make a list of a list of a list before the indexing became evident to me, but it makes sense now.